# How to hide or remove header Sec-Fetch-xxx in cefsharp 79.1.360

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Sample file
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/Handlers/ExampleResourceRequestHandler.cs

```
       //Example of setting User-Agent in every request.
        var headers = request.Headers;
        headers.Clear();

        var userAgent = headers["User-Agent"];
        headers["User-Agent"] = userAgent + " CefSharp";

        request.Headers = headers;
```

I grabbed the packet through fiddler and saw that the header contains "Sec-Fetch-

```
Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User:? 1 "
```

How can I hide or delete these?
I use "headers.Clear ()" but it has no effect

```
        var headers = request.Headers;
        foreach(string key in headers)
        {
            if (key.StartsWith("Sec-Fetch"))
            {
                request.SetHeaderByName(key, "", true);
            }
        }
```

Set to null, but only the sec-fech-xxx value has changed.

```
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
```

Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest trying to remove the headers from the collection rather than clearing it. Alternative try http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_IRequest_SetHeaderByName.htm

Comment: Does not work，Set to null, but only the sec-fech-xxx value has changed :Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1

Comment: You'll have to ask on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php

Comment: Please check my below answer, Hope it will be useful for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70910231/18068565