# Prevent Google Chrome from sending Sec-Fetch headers

Tags: caching, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, owin, owin-middleware

I would like to cache static content (index.html) in my web API 2 (net. framework 4.6.2 app)

I wrote OWIN middleware that adds a `cache-control` header to the response, allowing for subsequent requests to be retrieved from the browser cache.

The OWIN context extension:

```java
public static class BrowserCacheOwinContextExtensions {
  public static IOwinContext SetCacheControlHeader(this IOwinContext context, int maxAge) {
    context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = $"public, max-age={maxAge}";
    context.Response.Headers["Vary"] = "User-Agent";
        
    return context;
  } 
}
```

Snippet from middleware:

```java
if (browserCacheOptions.IsEnable) {
  context.SetCacheControlHeader(browserCacheOptions.MaxAge);
}

await context.Response.WriteAsync(file);
```

It works fine in the Mozilla browser but doesn't in Chrome.

Snippet from Mozilla:

[image]
[image]

I believe the root cause of this is that Chrome adds additional `Sec-Fetch` headers + `cache-control: max-age=0` to the request automatically.

[image]

Automatically added Sec-Fetch headers by Chrome:

[image]
[image]

Note: if open the same request at separate browser tab it works fine ever for Chrome (no `sec-fetch` headers in request)

**Q:** Is it possible to somehow disable such behaviour and don't add sec-fetch headers automatically to the request?

Or if you have other proposals, please do share them.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify the *sec-* as it is in [forbidden headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name) list.
This basically a list of headers that cannot be modified using the client side scripting.